# Cannot Mock<T> but can Mock<Interface>?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to build a mock factory, like this:

```
public Mock<T> CreateMock<T>(SomeParams someParams) where T : IMyInterface
{
    Mock<T> result = new Mock<T>();
    ...
}
```

However, I am getting the compiler error [CS0452](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0452?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0452)): *The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Mock'.*

Yet, when I tried this, it worked just fine:

```
public Mock<IMyInterface> CreateMock(SomeParams someParams)
{
    Mock<IMyInterface> result = new Mock<IMyInterface>();
    ...
}
```

I don't understand, why I am getting the compiler error, when the code is functionally the same? Is there any simple way to workaround this? I would like to avoid the second approach, as it would require considerable changes in our testing infrastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand, why I am getting the compiler error, when the code is functionally the same?

Consider this case:

```cs
public struct Awkward : IMyInterface
{
}
...
Mock<Awkward> mock = MockFactory.CreateMock<Awkward>();
```

That satisfies the constraint you've put on `CreateMock` - but `Awkward` is a value type. `Mock<T>` requires `T` to be a reference type.

You need to constrain the `T` type parameter in your method to be a *reference* type that implements the interface:

```cs
public Mock<T> CreateMock<T>(SomeParams someParams) where T : class, IMyInterface
```

Comment: Is there any way how to spread propagating the `class` type constraint? If I introduce it, all calling methods will now also need to check for `class`. Is it possible to do something like:

```
public Mock<T> CreateMockWrapper<T>(SomeParams someParams) where T : IMyInterface
{
    if (typeof(T) is class)
        return CreateMock<T>(someParams);
    return default;
```

Comment: @Storm: No, only *generic* calling methods (or methods within generic classes, using their type parameter as a type argument to the method) will need to require it to be a class... and chances are they should already have been doing so. (Ask yourself in each case whether you'd expect to be able to pass a type argument of `Awkward` in this case.)